# Help with Boost Spirit ASTs

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a small tool for analyzing simple B Machine substitutions as part of a college research work. The code successfully parse test inputs of the form mySubst := var1 + var2. However, I get a pop-up error message saying "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. " In the command prompt window, I get an "Assertion failed message". The main program is given below:

```
// BMachineTree.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

/*=============================================================================
    Copyright (c) 2010 Temitope Onunkun
=============================================================================*/
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  UUsing Boost Spririt Trees (AST) to parse B Machine Substitutions.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DUMP_PARSETREE_AS_XML

#include <boost/spirit/core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/tree/ast.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/tree/tree_to_xml.hpp>
#include "BMachineTreeGrammar.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

#if defined(BOOST_SPIRIT_DUMP_PARSETREE_AS_XML)
#include <map>
#endif

// Using AST to parse B Machine substitutions
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::spirit;

typedef char const*         iterator_t;
typedef tree_match<iterator_t> parse_tree_match_t;
typedef parse_tree_match_t::tree_iterator iter_t;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
string evaluate(parse_tree_match_t hit);
string eval_machine(iter_t const& i);

vector<string> dx;
string evaluate(tree_parse_info<> info)
{
    return eval_machine(info.trees.begin());
}

string eval_machine(iter_t const& i)
{
    cout << "In eval_machine. i->value = " <<
        string(i->value.begin(), i->value.end()) <<
        " i->children.size() = " << i->children.size() << endl;

    if (i->value.id() == substitution::leafValueID)
    {
        assert(i->children.size() == 0);

        // extract string tokens
        string leafValue(i->value.begin(), i->value.end());

                dx.push_back(leafValue.c_str());
        return leafValue.c_str();
    }
    //
    else if (i->value.id() == substitution::termID)
    {
        if ( (*i->value.begin() == '*') || (*i->value.begin() == '/') )
        {
            assert(i->children.size() == 2);

                        dx.push_back( eval_machine(i->children.begin()) );
                        dx.push_back( eval_machine(i->children.begin()+1) );
            return eval_machine(i->children.begin()) + " " +
                eval_machine(i->children.begin()+1);
        }
                //
       else
            assert(0);
    }
    else if (i->value.id() == substitution::expressionID)
    {
        if ( (*i->value.begin() == '+') || (*i->value.begin() == '-') )
        {
            assert(i->children.size() == 2);

                        dx.push_back( eval_machine(i->children.begin()) );
                        dx.push_back( eval_machine(i->children.begin()+1) );
            return eval_machine(i->children.begin()) + " " +
                eval_machine(i->children.begin()+1);
        }
                else
           assert(0);
        }
        //
        else if (i->value.id() == substitution::simple_substID)
    {
                if (*i->value.begin() == (':' >> '=') )
                {
                        assert(i->children.size() == 2);

                        dx.push_back( eval_machine(i->children.begin()) );
                        dx.push_back( eval_machine(i->children.begin()+1) );
            return eval_machine(i->children.begin()) + "|->" +
                eval_machine(i->children.begin()+1);

                }
        else
            assert(0);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(0); // error
    }

    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main()
{
    // look in BMachineTreeGrammar for the definition of BMachine
    substitution BMach_subst;

    cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    cout << "\t\tB Machine Substitution...\n\n";
    cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    cout << "Type an expression...or [q or Q] to quit\n\n";

    string str;
    while (getline(cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        tree_parse_info<> info = ast_parse(str.c_str(), BMach_subst, space_p);

        if (info.full)
        {
#if defined(BOOST_SPIRIT_DUMP_PARSETREE_AS_XML)
            // dump parse tree as XML
            std::map<parser_id, std::string> rule_names;
                        rule_names[substitution::identifierID] = "identifier";
            rule_names[substitution::leafValueID] = "leafValue";
            rule_names[substitution::factorID] = "factor";
            rule_names[substitution::termID] = "term";
            rule_names[substitution::expressionID] = "expression";
                        rule_names[substitution::simple_substID] = "simple_subst";
            tree_to_xml(cout, info.trees, str.c_str(), rule_names);
#endif

            // print the result
                        cout << "Variables in Vector dx: " << endl;
                        for(vector<string>::iterator idx = dx.begin(); idx < dx.end(); ++idx)
                                cout << *idx << endl;
            cout << "parsing succeeded\n";
            cout << "result = " << evaluate(info) << "\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "parsing failed\n";
        }
    }

    cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The grammar,  defined in  BMachineTreeGrammar.hpp file is given below:

```
/*=============================================================================
    Copyright (c) 2010 Temitope Onunkun
    http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/pg/onun

    Use, modification and distribution is subject to the Boost Software
    License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
    http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
=============================================================================*/
#ifndef BOOST_SPIRIT_BMachineTreeGrammar_HPP_
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_BMachineTreeGrammar_HPP_

using namespace boost::spirit;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Using Boost Spririt Trees (AST) to parse B Machine Substitutions.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  B Machine Grammar
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct substitution : public grammar<substitution>
{
        static const int identifierID = 1;
    static const int leafValueID = 2;
    static const int factorID = 3;
    static const int termID = 4;
    static const int expressionID = 5;
        static const int simple_substID = 6;


    template <typename ScannerT>
    struct definition
    {
        definition(substitution const& )
        {
            //  Start grammar definition
            identifier   = alpha_p >> (+alnum_p | ch_p('_') )
                                                ;

                        leafValue        = leaf_node_d[
                                                        lexeme_d[ identifier | +digit_p ] ]
                                                ;

                        factor          = leafValue
                                                | inner_node_d[ ch_p( '(' ) >> expression
                                                >> ch_p(')' ) ]
                                                ;

                        term            = factor >>
                                                  *(  (root_node_d[ch_p('*') ] >> factor )
                                                    | (root_node_d[ch_p('/') ] >> factor )
                                                   );

                        expression       = term >>
                                                  *(  (root_node_d[ch_p('+') ] >> term )
                                                    | (root_node_d[ch_p('-') ] >> term )
                                                   );

                        simple_subst= leaf_node_d[
                                                        lexeme_d[ identifier ] ]
                                                >> root_node_d[str_p(":=")] >> expression
                                                ;

            //  End grammar definition

            // turn on the debugging info.
                        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(identifier);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(leafValue);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(factor);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(term);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(expression);
                        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(simple_subst);
        }

                rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<simple_substID> > simple_subst;
        rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<expressionID> >   expression;
        rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<termID> >         term;
        rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<factorID> >       factor;
        rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<leafValueID> >    leafValue;
                rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<identifierID> >   identifier;

        rule<ScannerT, parser_context<>, parser_tag<simple_substID> > const&
        start() const { return simple_subst; }
    };
};

#endif
```

The output I get on running the program is:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                B Machine Substitution...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Type an expression...or [q or Q] to quit

mySubst := var1 - var2

parsing succeeded
In eval_machine. i->value = := i->children.size() = 2
Assertion failed: 0, file c:\redmound\bmachinetree\bmachinetree\bmachinetree.cpp
, line 114
```

I will appreciate any help in resolving this problem.

Comment: For new projects I very much suggest not to use the older Spirit.Classic version (as you do), but to utilize the newer Spirit V2.x which has been released with Boost V1.41. The new version is not only a lot easier to use, it's quite a bit faster at parse time as well.

Comment: Thanks, hkaiser. I am reading up on Spirit.Qi at the moment. I will appreciate any assistance to convert the code into  a Qi compatible one.

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion fails on line 114 because you assume every node will have an associated ID. They won't: in this case, none of the operators you define (`:=`, `+`, `-`, etc.) will have IDs associated with them.

FWIW, @hkaiser is right: you really should be using Spirit V2. Its notion of ASTs is much better than classic Spirit (much easier to use, too).